# how to push data from api into datasets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

how to push data from API into data sets to display multi line chart.i have given data model that my API returns. and also the script below

how to insert data and label from API data into data set and label to display multi line chart
in API data first array represents LABEL and Second Third Array for data.

```
      <script>
     data() {
     return {

        labels: [ ],
         result:'',
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Data One",
           data: [ ]
         },
          {
          label: "Data Two", 
          data: [ ]
          }
        ]
       };
     }

  var self=this;
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:5000/api/city" )
        .then(res => { 
         self.result = res.data;
         //console.log(self.result )
         self.labels = self.result[0];
         self.datasets[0].data=self.result[1];
         self.datasets[1].data=self.result[2];
         console.log('label',self.labels)
          this.renderChart(
            {
              labels: [],
              datasets: this.datasets
            },
            { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
          );
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error:", error);
        });



        //below is my API data

       [
          ["2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-02","2014-01-03","2014-01-04"], 
          [1,11,12,10,4],
          [14,4,14,12,4] 
       ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your assign data seems OK. But when you are calling `renderChart()` to draw the chart, you are assigning the `labels` as an empty array. It should be:

```
self.renderChart(
    {labels: self.labels, datasets: self.datasets}, 
    {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
);
```

More about [**renderChart**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs)

**I have a suggestion for you here:**

Inside `then()` callback function `this` is refers to that callback function. Consequently, `this.datasets` might be undefined, as well as `this.renderChart`. So you should use `self` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

**Here you go:**

```
var self = this;
axios
  .get("http://localhost:5000/api/city")
  .then(res => {
    self.result = res.data;
    let [labels, ...data] = res.data;

    self.labels = labels;
    let dataSet = data.map((item, index) => {
      return {
        label: labels[index],
        data: item
      };
    });

    this.renderChart(
      {
        labels: [],
        datasets: dataSet
      },
      { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
    );
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  });
```